# How to match semver regex?

Tags: regex, jq, semantic-versioning

I'm trying to parse some json field which contains a semantic version. I'm trying the semver regex for that from the [semver site](https://semver.org/#is-there-a-suggested-regular-expression-regex-to-check-a-semver-string).

Semver regex:

```
^(0|[1-9]\d*)\.(0|[1-9]\d*)\.(0|[1-9]\d*)(?:-((?:0|[1-9]\d*|\d*[a-zA-Z-][0-9a-zA-Z-]*)(?:\.(?:0|[1-9]\d*|\d*[a-zA-Z-][0-9a-zA-Z-]*))*))?(?:\+([0-9a-zA-Z-]+(?:\.[0-9a-zA-Z-]+)*))?$
```

How could I do this in jq:

```
match(^(0|[1-9]\d*)\.(0|[1-9]\d*)\.(0|[1-9]\d*)(?:-((?:0|[1-9]\d*|\d*[a-zA-Z-][0-9a-zA-Z-]*)(?:\.(?:0|[1-9]\d*|\d*[a-zA-Z-][0-9a-zA-Z-]*))*))?(?:\+([0-9a-zA-Z-]+(?:\.[0-9a-zA-Z-]+)*))?$
)
```

gives a compilation error:

```
jq: error: syntax error, unexpected INVALID_CHARACTER (Unix shell quoting issues?) at <top-level>, line 1:
match(^(0|[1-9]\d*)\.(0|[1-9]\d*)\.(0|[1-9]\d*)(?:-((?:0|[1-9]\d*|\d*[a-zA-Z-][0-9a-zA-Z-]*)(?:\.(?:0|[1-9]\d*|\d*[a-zA-Z-][0-9a-zA-Z-]*))*))?(?:\+([0-9a-zA-Z-]+(?:\.[0-9a-zA-Z-]+)*))?$

      
jq: 1 compile error
exit status 3
```

Comment: Please show use sample input & expected output in a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Try quoting the regex with single quotes

Comment: You must quote the regex string and escape the backslashes: `match("^(0|[1-9]\\d*)\\. …")` – VTC, this is nothing more than a typo

Answer (score 1):

Consider passing your regex as an [`--arg`](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#Invokingjq) to [jq](/questions/tagged/jq), this will keeps quoting simple, and prevents your filter from becoming unreadable:

```bash
$ regex='^(0|[1-9]\d*)\.(0|[1-9]\d*)\.(0|[1-9]\d*)(?:-((?:0|[1-9]\d*|\d*[a-zA-Z-][0-9a-zA-Z-]*)(?:\.(?:0|[1-9]\d*|\d*[a-zA-Z-][0-9a-zA-Z-]*))*))?(?:\+([0-9a-zA-Z-]+(?:\.[0-9a-zA-Z-]+)*))?$'
$
$ jq --arg regex "$regex" 'match($regex)' <<< '"1.0.0-beta"'
{
  "offset": 0,
  "length": 10,
  "string": "1.0.0-beta",
  "captures": [
    {
      "offset": 0,
      "length": 1,
      "string": "1",
      "name": null
    },
    {
      "offset": 2,
      "length": 1,
      "string": "0",
      "name": null
    },
    {
      "offset": 4,
      "length": 1,
      "string": "0",
      "name": null
    },
    {
      "offset": 6,
      "length": 4,
      "string": "beta",
      "name": null
    },
    {
      "offset": -1,
      "string": null,
      "length": 0,
      "name": null
    }
  ]
}
$
```

Comment: How to do in script like this with separate filter var?

`#!/bin/bash

semver_regex="\"^(0|[1-9]\d*)\.(0|[1-9]\d*)\.(0|[1-9]\d*)(?:-((?:0|[1-9]\d*|\d*[a-zA-Z-][0-9a-zA-Z-]*)(?:\.(?:0|[1-9]\d*|\d*[a-zA-Z-][0-9a-zA-Z-]*))*))?(?:\+([0-9a-zA-Z-]+(?:\.[0-9a-zA-Z-]+)*))?$\""
artifact="my-artifact"

harbor_url="https://harbor/api/v2.0/projects/xyz/repositories/$artifact/artifacts?page=1&page_size=1&sort=-push_time"
harbor_json=$(curl -sS "${harbor_url}")

jq_filter=".[].tags[] | select(.name? | match(<regex here>)) | .name"
latest_version=$(echo "$harbor_json" | jq -r "${jq_filter}")`